# ReSharper SDK test for Context Action doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, resharper-9.0, resharper-sdk

I try to test my custom ReSharper Context Action using ReSharper SDK built-in test infrastucture. I've created an input file, an output file (`.gold`) and run the test. Two problems occur:

1. Test is always successful (even if input and `.gold` files are
   completely different, or empty etc.);
2. There is no `.tmp` file appears along with input and `.gold` files.

However, if I rename input file, then the test run fails with "file does not exist" exception.

My test project's structure is the same as described in [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/devguide/Extensions/Plugins/Testing/ProjectStructure.html).

**TestEnvironment.cs:**

```
[assembly: RequiresSTA]

[ZoneDefinition]
public class TestEnvironmentZone : ITestsZone, IRequire<PsiFeatureTestZone>
{
}

[SetUpFixture]
public class ReSharperTestEnvironmentAssembly : ExtensionTestEnvironmentAssembly<TestEnvironmentZone>
{
}
```

**Test class:**

```
[TestFixture]
public class FooContextActionTests : ContextActionTestBase<FooContextAction>
{
    protected override void ProcessAction(Func<FooContextAction> action, ITextControl control, ISolution solution)
    {
    }

    protected override string ExtraPath { get; }

    protected override string RelativeTestDataPath => @"FooContextActionTests";

    [Test]
    public void Test01()
    {
        DoTestFiles("Test01.cs");
    }
}
```

I've made the similar test for simple quick-fix. That test works as expected and reacts to any change of input or `.gold` file. So the question is how to test Context Action properly.

ReSharper SDK 9.2 is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! These steps resolve the problem:

1. Update to ReSharper.SDK v10 (it is not mandatory, I guess);
2. Change base test class from `ContextActionTestBase` to `CSharpContextActionExecuteTestBase`;
3. Set the `ExtraPath` property value as equal to `RelativeTestDataPath` value (this value is the folder name where input and gold-file are located).
4. Remove `ProcessAction` override.

This test class works correctly:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FooContextActionTests  : CSharpContextActionExecuteTestBase<FooContextAction>
{
    protected override string ExtraPath => "FooContextActionTests";

    protected override string RelativeTestDataPath => "FooContextActionTests";

    [Test]
    public void Test01()
    {
        DoTestFiles("Test01.cs");
    }
}
```